# passing ./configure flags when you work in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, configure, building

I tried to build library `wolfssl` with some feature, it can be enabled via `–enable-sha` flag during `./configure`. Like `./configure –enable-sha`

Everything works fine under Linux, but now I need to built it under Windows using visual studio solution. The `*.sln` file presented in repo, but I totally confused with this configure argument.
I am not sure that Visual Studio run `configure` script. Even if I am wrong, I can't find any option in solution properties to pass `–enable-sha` to `configure`.

Answer (score 1):

What an excellent question! You are correct in that ./configure does not work in Visual Studio. For each configure option there is a corresponding CFLAG or set of CFLAGs that can be used to enable the same functionality. To set the CLFAGS in Visual Studio wolfSSL already has configured the windows projects with the setting `WOLFSSL_USER_SETTINGS`. This makes it easy for users to add new settings to the header file in `wolfssl-root/IDE/WIN/user_settings.h` and have them automatically pulled in when building the library!

You mentioned --enable-sha so if we look at the configure.ac file in `wolfssl-root/configure.ac` and search for that setting we will see the below:

```
 # SHA                                                                            
 AC_ARG_ENABLE([sha],                                                             
     [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-sha],[Enable SHA (default: enabled)])],            
     [ ENABLED_SHA=$enableval ],                                                  
     [ ENABLED_SHA=yes ]                                                          
     )                                                                            

 if test "$ENABLED_SHA" = "no"                                                    
 then                                                                             
     AM_CFLAGS="$AM_CFLAGS -DNO_SHA -DNO_OLD_TLS"                                 
 else                                                                             
     # turn off SHA if leanpsk or leantls on                                      
     if test "$ENABLED_LEANPSK" = "yes" || test "$ENABLED_LEANTLS" = "yes"        
     then                                                                         
         AM_CFLAGS="$AM_CFLAGS -DNO_SHA -DNO_OLD_TLS"                             
         ENABLED_SHA=no                                                           
     fi                                                                           
 fi
```

What we can glean from the above logic is that SHA is enabled by default and you only need to set a macro if you are looking to disable it!

So to turn on SHA functionality in windows you would remove any pre-processor settings for `NO_SHA` or to disable it obviously then add the setting `NO_SHA`. Notice also that old TLS has a dependency on sha so when disabling it you would also want to set `NO_OLD_TLS` based on the rules in configure.ac!

wolfSSL has other functionality that is OFF by default. In those cases you have to define something like `WOLFSSL_FEATURE` or `HAVE_FEATURE` to enable it. Again you can use configure.ac as a reference or you can review the wolfSSL manual on our website under the "Docs" tab in the section "Featured"! You may find [Chapter 2 Section 2.3 "Building on Windows](https://www.wolfssl.com/docs/wolfssl-manual/ch2/)" helpful as it details the info I provided above.

I would also recommend checking out these sections in Chapter 2:

Chapter 2 Section 2.4.1 REMOVING FEATURES

Chapter 2 Section 2.4.2 ENABLING FEATURES DISABLED BY DEFAULT

NOTE: For any future questions pertaining to wolfSSL if you add the tag "wolfssl" to your question we will get an email letting us know you have posted a question on stack overflow! One of our staff would be more than happy to answer your question. If you experience a long delay while waiting for a reply shoot us an email anytime at support@wolfssl.com with a link to your stack overflow question and we will be happy to look into it!